# How do I determine the address of the cell with a target value if the range has multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data consists of unique first names arranged in a two-dimensional range (for example, A1:E10). I want to determine the cell address of a certain target value. The formula I have built works but it relies on me creating a formula that uses the MATCH function for each column then combines those (with some convoluted math) to get the address. Here is a screenshot of the spreadsheet:

[image: screenshot of the spreadsheet]

In the final spreadsheet the number of columns will vary so I need to eliminate the need to create a different formula for each column. I feel like some application of array formulas will work but I can't seem to crack it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named the range to search (although you can certainly use the addressing without the name, if you prefer):

```
myRange:  Refers To: $A$1:$F$10
```

Then you can use:

```
=ADDRESS(MAX((I2=myRange)*ROW(myRange)),MAX((I2=myRange)*COLUMN(myRange)))
```

[image]